# Does netbeans come with built in php interpreters?

Tags: php, netbeans

My ubuntu linux system has the following php interpreter.

```
PHP 5.5.9
```

I am using netbeans for a php development project. `Tools-> options-> php-> General ->php interpreter` points to `/usr/bin/php` which is the version above mentioned.

But when I create a new php project, I can choose many different versions of php5 as the interpter in netbeans (`5.1/5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6`). From where did these other versions of php interpreters come from? Were they built in to netbans ide?

Comment: No, NetBeans does not come with an interpreter. This setting is to specify what parsing rules to apply to your code. For example, if you specify 5.2, you want namespaces to be indicated as a syntax error.

Comment: so that it can warn me when I am writing something which isn't valid in a specific version?

Comment: so can i say that netbeans comes with built in php parsers(not interpreters) for different versions..

Comment: Yes, that would be a fair way of putting it. In general you should set it to the lowest version you support, so that if you do something that requires a higher version, it will warn you in the project and editor panels.

Comment: great! that is a good feature and that clears my confusion..